# Were Words omitted?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 53:10

AKJV Yet it pleased the LORD to bruise him; he has put him to grief: when you shall make his soul an offering for sin, he shall see his seed, he shall prolong his days, and the pleasure of the LORD shall prosper in his hand.

BBE And the Lord was pleased...see a seed, long life, ...will do well in his hand. ...

What is the reason for this translation by BBE?

Answer (score 4):

It is obvious from the [Wikipedia article on the BBE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_in_Basic_English) that the Bible in Basic English does not pretend to be an academic and reliable translation. It is specifically designed for people with limited language ability or for persons to whom English is a second language. I think it must be quite apparent why its translation will not equate to the KJV.

And it must be obvious that much of the underlying Greek and Hebrew texts could not be correctly rendered, given the self-imposed restrictions of Professor Hooke's personal project.

The article does not quote Professor Hooke himself but I would suppose that he himself did not expect people to stay with his own bible version, rather I assume he envisaged it to be a learning tool as a first step towards the use of more standard versions.

> The Bible In Basic English (also known as BBE) is a translation of the Bible into Basic English. The BBE was translated by Professor S. H. Hooke using the standard 850 Basic English words. 100 words that were helpful to understand poetry were added along with 50 "Bible" words for a total of 1,000 words. This version is effective in communicating the Bible to those with limited education or where English is a second language. The New Testament was released in 1941 and the Old Testament was released in 1949.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_in_Basic_English)